# sql query for row replacing with another row

Tags: sql

i have a query below

```
select id, name || ' ' || name as name, manager_id from table order by id;
```

it returns

```
id name manager_id
 1 a             3
 2 b             3
 3 c             3
```

i want to print the name c in place of manager_id is 3.

Comment: Please don't add random RDBMS tags to your question, MySQL, SQL Server and Postgre are all different products and work very differently. This, however, is clearly not SQL Server, as `||` isn't valid T-SQL (T-SQL uses `+` for string concatenation). Please tag the RDBMS you are using and **only** the RDBMS you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use left join and join with the same tables two times by using alias which is called self join

```
   select t1.id, t1.name , 
   t2.name as managername
   from table_name t1
   left join table_name t2
   on  t1.id=t2.manager_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `JOIN` :

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.name AS Manger
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t2.id = t1.manager_id
ORDER by t1.id;
```

If that is in same table then you can do `self join` :

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t1.name AS Manger
FROM table t LEFT JOIN
     table t1
     ON t1.id = t.manager_id;
```

Comment: I *think* the OP is more likely after a `JOIN` here if I'm honest. `manager_id` is a foreign key pointing back to `id` of the same table.